# Better javascript library for sortable elements than jQuery Sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a better sortable JavaScript library in order to make some elements sortable than jQuery sortable method.

---

---- Update ----

I though it was obvious that the jQuery library has some issues with sorting Containers and Directions. Also it has some problems with some kind of elements. For example for some sort of elements inside elements (like Div inside Table or reverse) jQuery in some situations can't really perform in the correct way, for example you drag an element over another sortable element but it wont pusht the element to take it's place.
Also based on the browser version and type it's behavior can change. That's why I asked this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem, for now I'm happy about YUI 3 behavior. It's a mature library and offers more UI functionalities than jQueryUI. Coming from jQuery, it's not so immediate at first, but you'll get used to it soon.

[Checkout this sorting example](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/examples/dd/list-drag.html)